# cordova save edited image to specific directory

Tags: cordova

I need to save image after I edit and cropped it in specific directory
but it gives error.

**Image URL**

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAoCAYAAACfKfiZAAAA9ElEQVRYh‌​dXUuw0CMQwGYBdwgooKCV`

**Code**

```
function SavePic(file){ 
     var d = new Date();
     var n = d.getTime();
     //new file name
     var newFileName = n + ".jpg";

     currentDir.getFile(newFileName,{create: true,exclusive:false},function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
         var path = fileEntry.fullPath.replace(newFileName,"");
         fileEntry.remove();
         var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
         fileTransfer.download(file, path+""+fileName,function(theFile){

             alert("File Downloaded Successfully");
         },function(error){
               alert("File Download Failed"+ error.code);
           });
     },fail);
}
```

as i get "File Download Failed" alert from error function

Comment: Are you testing on Android Marshmallow?

Comment: Cordova file plugin has got permission issues with folder creation in marshmallow.this issue is fixed but not released yet as far as I know.you may have to pull the latest code from file plugin git and try again